# Taking a 'relative' limit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism

I am looking at Hamiltonians for specific physical situations. I have taken a given Hamiltonian $\vec{H}(\vec{p}, \vec{x})$ and have found the following Hamiltonian equations:
$$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} = \frac{\vec{p}c^2}{\sqrt{m_0^2c^4 + |\vec{p}|^2c^2}}$$
and further that
$$\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt} = -\nabla V(\vec{x}).$$
I am now instructed to take the limit $\|\vec{p}| << m_0c$. I have not come across this kind of limit notation in the past - what precisely does it mean?

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: If A<<B, this means that A is much, much smaller than B. Given that you have p<<mc, I would assume they would want you to take a Taylor expansion assuming pc very small.

Comment: Would you mean I should start differentiating with respect to $t$, given that $\vec{p}$ abd $\vec{x}$ are functions of $t$ also? It's been a long while since I last did Taylor series! Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: I would suggest factoring out an mc^2 term from the denominator. This puts your question into a well-known Taylor expansion for $1/\sqrt{1+x}$. You will get a familiar result for $dx/dt$.

Comment: Another point to make... Before you start calculating, what do you expect the answer to be? Without doing any work you should already know the leading order terms in the Taylor series, just from what you already know about newtonian physics.

Comment: I have worked through the problem using your suggested factoring, and I can see we end up with $v = \frac{p}{m}$ as expected. But I don't see where the Taylor expansion was used? I simply used the fact that $\sqrt{1 + (\frac{p}{mc})^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$.

How do you suggest using the expansion?

Answer (score 0):

This notation means that momentum is very small compared with $m_0c$, which means that is non relativistic (classic mechanics).

In the limit you will have 
$$\frac{d\boldsymbol x}{dt} = \frac{\boldsymbol pc^2}{m_0c^2} = \frac{\boldsymbol p}{m_0} = \boldsymbol v$$
as expected in classical mechanics.